# Improper integral of Euler constant

Tags: improper-integrals

What about whether or not this integral converges:

$$\int_0^\infty x^\alpha(\text{log}_e(x))^ne^{-x}\text{d}x\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(\star)$$

$\alpha,n,x:=\begin{cases}\alpha\in\mathbb{R^+}\cup\text{(-1, 0]}\\n\in\mathbb{N}\\x\in\mathbb{R^+}\cup\text{{0}}\end{cases}$

Here's what I did:

From $\mathcal{E}$uler's definition$$\:\:\Gamma(\alpha+1):=\int_0^1 (-\text{log}_e(x)\text{)}^{\alpha}\text{d}x$$$\\$Let$\:\:\text{log}_e(x):=\ln(x)\:;\:\mu=-\ln(x)\to\text{d}x=-\text{d}\mu\cdot e^{-\mu}$

Hence after some simplifications,$$\Gamma(\alpha+1)=\int_0^\infty\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\:\text{d}\mu$$

Now, under $\mathcal{L}$eibniz rule

$$\Gamma^{(1)}(\alpha+1):=\Gamma^{\large '}(\alpha+1)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha+1)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\:\text{d}\mu=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\:\text{d}\mu$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\ln(\mu)\:\text{d}\mu\:,\:\:\:\:\:\:\mu>0
$$

Assume$$\Gamma^{(n-1)}(\alpha+1)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\ln^{n-1}(\mu)\:\text{d}\mu\:,\:\:\:\:\:\:\mu>0;\:n\in\mathbb{N}$$Then$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}\Gamma^{(n-1)}(\alpha+1)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\alpha}\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\ln^{n-1}(\mu)\:\text{d}\mu=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\ln^{n}(\mu)\text{d}\mu=\Gamma^{(n)}(\alpha+1)$$

Hence$\:(\star):=\Gamma^{(n)}(\alpha+1)$

We can see that if$\:\:\mu\in(0,1],\:\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\ln^{n}(\mu)\le\mu^\alpha e^{-\mu (n+1)}\le e^{\alpha-\mu (n+1)}\:$

Thus,$$e^{\alpha}\int_0^1 e^{-\mu (n+1)}\text{d}\mu<\infty$$

If $\:\:\mu\in(1,\infty),\:\mu^\alpha\:e^{-\mu}\ln^{n}(\mu)\le \ln^n(\mu)e^{-\mu/2}\le \mathcal C< 1$

Thus,$$\mathcal C\int_1^\infty \text{d}\mu<\infty$$

We conclude that$\:\:\Gamma^{(n)}(\alpha+1)\:$converges in$\:\mathbb{R}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\square$

Now if everything's fine, how can I find the value of the integral?

Comment: Your initial integral stisfies $\int_0^\infty x^\alpha(\text{log}_e(x))^ne^{-x}\text{d}x=\Gamma^{(n)}(\alpha+1)$. Are you looking for a closed form of $\Gamma^{(n)}(\alpha+1)$?

Comment: Yes! I'm quite sure I can use the Euler constant

Comment: What's up with $\mathcal{C}$apitalisation?

Comment: Thought these guys deserved some fancy treatment